# jquery override important css style

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to apply a css style like so:

```
$(".data-rendering").css("background-size", "contain");
```

but this has this css already applied to it:

```
element.style {
    background: url(/Images/renderings/vista-ridge-macnab.jpg) 0px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Is there away to override this?

I have tried using .style but that did not work, I got an error saying .style does not exists.

Comment: Just include an `!important` in your override, since there's one in the stylesheet already. Yours will take precedence because it's inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method would be to use jQuery to add a class, and style that class below your element.style class.

```
$(".data-rendering").addClass("background-contain");

element.style {
    background: url(/Images/renderings/vista-ridge-macnab.jpg) 0px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.background-contain {
    background-size: contain !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
    <link rel= "stylesheet"  href="bad script you dont want that is causing"> problem>
```

1. Download your jquery javascript and style sheet locally.
2. Paste that particular script at the very top of your web app for example

(This normally is where the site.css normally is. Putting it at the top  will take precedent over the bad style-sheet that has the !important or inline-styles as you like to call them.)

3.If that fails, just take your code snippet  $( '.data-rendering' ).css("cssText", "background-size:contain !important;"); and put it in the top of your page and erase the inline-styles that are causing your problems

Answer (score -1):

you can try this , it should works

```
$( '.data-rendering' ).css("cssText", "background-size:contain !important;");
```

and this also works fine .

```
$(".data-rendering").attr('style', 'background-size:contain !important;');
```

Comment: No need for !important in an inline style as inline styles trump any other css for the element applied anyway

Comment: not if the style you want to override has !important . !important has the first priority

Comment: Granted, but if you need that many !importants, you probably should just rewrite your CSS in most cases